# Unable to successfully change wordpress site URL

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm trying to set up Wordpress with Multisite, and the first thing I'm trying to do after getting the [Bitnami AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NN8XE6S) running on an EC2 host is assign an Elastic IP. However, as soon as I assign this, I'm unable to get to my Wordpress login page due to redirect issues.

When I try to go to my new URL of `http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`, I get redirected to `http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/wp-signup.php?new=ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`, with a redirect loop error shown by my browser. (The IP address, noted with x's, is the same in all 3 cases).

Also, as expected, my apache `access_log` spits out 20 of the following lines when I try to access my site:

`[05/Jun/2016:19:56:41 +0000] "GET /wp-signup.php?new=ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com HTTP/1.1" 302 -`

**Things that do work**

- Before I assign the Elastic IP, I can access the Wordpress site from `http://ec2-yy-yy-yy-yy.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`, as long as I dont make any changes to the site URL after spinning up the EC2 instance with the Bitnami Wordpress AMI.
- After assigning the Elastic IP, I can SSH into the EC2 instance with both the new IP and the corresponding *.compute.amazonaws.com hostname.

**Things I tried**

Following [these steps](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL), I've...

- Updated `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` in my `wp-config.php`, as well as updated `site_url` and `home` to match the new hostname.
- Added `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` to my `wp-config.php`
- Added the `RELOCATE` flag

None of those appear to fix the redirection issue.

Answer (score 0):

Aha - I found another link that states migrating a Multisite setup is a bit more involved, and requires searching through all database tables for any references to the old hostname:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Searching through all the tables in phpmyadmin... I did find some more references! After updating all of these, I can now get to my site using the new Elastic IP.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami stacks come with a tool to automatically configure the machine IP of the installation. In the case of WordPress, you just need to SSH into your machine and execute the following command:

```
 sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --machine_hostname NEW_DOMAIN
```

Hope it helps.